# ko.computed solo funciona para la última fila

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

Estoy comenzando a aprender `knockout.js` el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre:</th>
            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
            <th>Apellido Materno</th>
            <th>Full Name:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: alumnos">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: nombre"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: a_paterno"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: a_materno"/></td>
            <td data-bind="text: fullname"></td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
function nuevoAlumno(nombre){
    self = this;
    self.nombre = ko.observable(nombre);
    self.a_paterno = ko.observable();
    self.a_materno = ko.observable();
    self.fullname = ko.computed(function(){
        var nombre = self.a_paterno();
        return nombre;
    });
}

function alumnosViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.alumnos = ko.observableArray([
        new nuevoAlumno('lup'),
        new nuevoAlumno('ant'),
        new nuevoAlumno('antd')
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new alumnosViewModel());
```

Aparentemente el código está bien pero al momento de correrlo el evento `ko.computed` para obtener el fullname solo funciona para la última fila agregada a la tabla, en el ejemplo solo funciona para la fila 3 y al momento de calcularla escribe el fullname por igual para todas las filas.

Answer (score 4):

Por fin descubrí cual era el problema con el código

```
function nuevoAlumno(nombre){
    self = this;
    // ...
}
```

El problema es la manera que declaraste `self`, olvidaste usar `var`, por lo tanto `self` se convierte en una variable global y es por eso que ocurre ese efecto extraño.

Simplemente usa

```
var self = this;
```

para solucionarlo.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era por no haber puesto var para limitar el alcance de la variable. muchas gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: @Europpa si esta respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score -2):

Puedo ver que trabajas con una lista de alumnos, pero me pregunto cuando invocas al nuevoAlumno() como referencias la instancia de un item en la coleccion? porque alli solo veo que pasas un nombre, usas una funcion como clase cuando deberias usar un objeto json

Donde veo el problema esta en el uso del "this", este se esta aplicando en un contexto que no es el correcto

No evaluaste crear un JSON como array para hacerlo observable
[Loading and Saving JSON data](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)
Analiza el ejemplo y veras como a un json tambien le puedes definir un ko.computed()

Deberias usar un [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)
Pero veras que se hace un push() de cada item con un nuevo objeto json

Entiendo que el ejemplo que planteas lo tomaste de aqui [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)
Pero veras que alli usa solo una unica entidad y el "this" aplica al viewmodel, no esta dentro de un array, es por eso que propuse usar un json

saludos

Comment: Si tienes dudas con respecto a la pregunta sería mejor que lo dejaras en un comentario(como este por ejemplo).